# check connection jpype - java

Tags: java, python, jvm, jpype

Is there a way to check the connection between jpype and java other than a print statement?
I have installed jpype in anaconda (Windows 10 64bit, anaconda python27 (64bit) and jpype from the anaconda cloud). I can import jpype and create javaclasses and javaojects. However, when I try to get a print statement nothing happens and I can't figure out why.

```
from jpype import *
getDefaultJVMPath()

Out[2]: u'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_131\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll'

startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath(), "-ea")
java.lang.System.out.println("JPYPE WORKS !")
```

No print statement

```
javaPackage = JPackage("java.lang")
javaClass = javaPackage.String
javaObject = javaClass("Hello, Jpype")
javaObject

Out[8]: <jpype._jclass.java.lang.String at 0xc1b8b70>

java.lang.System.out.println(javaObject)
```

No print statement

The getDefaultJVMPath() is correct. But I can't get the connection with the jvm to work and I can't figure out where it goes wrong.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That's the case when you're using Jupyter Notebook. It works well if you're executing it in Python console or by using a .py file. If you're wondering why it worked for `getDefaultJVMPath()`, here is why

```
type(getDefaultJVMPath())
```

returns 'str'. But

```
type(java.lang.System.out.println("JPYPE WORKS !"))
```

returns 'NoneType'

Hope that helps!